# I can't get on the internet via a wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless

This computer, (running Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric) I'm writing from is connected to the inet via Clearwire modem, to Belkin N600 DB wireless router (ethernet cable). This router successfully connects via wireless to a laptop in this house.

My problem is my computer (Dell Dimension 4500) in an adjacent room is successfully connected (by eth cable) to a Netgear N300 Wireless Router WNR2000 v2, but I can't connect it, via wireless, to my Belkin router. That computer does get inet access if I physically swap it to the same setup I have in this room.

Comment: My "problem computer" is also running Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric

Comment: what is the result of `rfkill list all` and `sudo lshw -class network` ?  Edit your question with the output of these statements.

Comment: Downvoted, question appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Try searching "drivers" in the dash, then clicking "Additional Drivers". See if your NIC has drivers available. If it does, install it. Hope this helps!